# Calculating Percentage of Multiple Data Groups and Grouping by Name

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a mach-up of what my table looks like:
[image]

What I am attempting to do is calculate the `Opt-In` percentage of each `"Name"` separate from all the others. The response data would look something like this:
[image]

I have played around with a solution, here is my code so far:

```
SELECT 'Hunters Treat Shop' AS "Organization", cast(A.NUM as float)/cast(A.DENOM as float) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM
(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM report
WHERE Name = 'Hunters Treat Shop'
AND Opt-In = TRUE
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]) AS NUM,

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM report
WHERE Name = 'Hunters Treat Shop'
AND Thank-You Delivered = TRUE
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]) AS DENOM) A

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Julianas Treat Shop' AS "Organization", cast(A.NUM as float)/cast(A.DENOM as float) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM
(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM report
WHERE Name = 'Julianas Treat Shop'
AND Opt-In = TRUE
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]) AS NUM,

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM report
WHERE Name = 'Julianas Treat Shop'
AND Thank-You Delivered = TRUE
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]) AS DENOM) A
```

This query works as intended, but I would need to repeat and union twice more in order to get the intended result.

Comment: @Strawberry Apologies, I have updated the query to reflect my data samples shown.

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your query has to do with the question, but you can use aggregation based on the data you describe:

```
select name, avg( opt_in = 'true' ) as opt_in_ratio
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated my query to reflect the question more accurately.